# I like to add quotes inside a string gathered from the readLine()

Tags: java

The output is

`INSERT INTO 'products'('productid', 'color', 'size', 'price') VALUES ('purse8901, red, small handbag, 70.00');`

I would like to have the single straight quotes added so that I can import the converted sql file easily into the database again like this:

```
INSERT INTO 'products'('productid', 'color', 'size', 'price') VALUES 
('purse8901', 'red', 'small handbag', '70.00');
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to split the sCurrentLine string and add \' above.

```
package ConvertCSVtoSQL;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Convert {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String begin = "INSERT INTO `produts`(`productid`, `color`. `size`, 

`price`) VALUES ('";
        File fileToSave = new File("C:\\Users\\Blue\\Desktop\\sql\

\products.sql");
            if (!fileToSave.exists()) {
            fileToSave.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileToSave.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write('\n');
        String end = "');";
        String sCurrentLine;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Blue\\Desktop\

\products.csv"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Convert.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, 

ex);
        }
        br.readLine();
        for (int count = 1; count <= 236; count++) {
            sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
            bw.write(begin + sCurrentLine + end);
            bw.write('\n');
        }
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for something like this:-

```
String name = "\'productid\'";
```